# Can I get the current GPS location of a tablet using Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, tablet

I like to know if is possible to get the location ot an android tablet using Jquery mobile/Phonegap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function.

Here is the official doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition